# how to set view in middle between two uiview using constraint in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have developed one app in `swift` `xcode 6.0.1` in that i can use storyboard, and in this three `UIView` 1st `UIView` set in top and 3rd `UIView` set in bottom and i have set 2nd `UIView` in middle so how that can possible

Please give your answer...

Comment: You mean with code or using Interface Builder (storyboard)?

Comment: using Interface Builder